# Change Graphics2D Shape

Tags: java, graphics, shapes

Hey I want to create program where u can draw multishape like Circle,Rectagle,Line .When i clicked circle button and drew Circle(1) and then when i Clicked Rectangle it should draw only Rectangle, not Circle and Rectangle(2) ,When i Clicked Line its should draw only Line not Circle and Rectangle and Line(3).

[image]

```
public class Images extends JComponent {


    private Image image;

    private Graphics2D g2;

    private int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;

    public Images() {
        setDoubleBuffered(false);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {

            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            clear();
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }


    public void line() {
        currentX = 0;
        currentY = 0;
        oldX = 0;
        oldY = 0;

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY));
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void rectangle() {
        currentX = 0;
        currentY = 0;
        oldX = 0;
        oldY = 0;
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(oldX, oldY, currentX - oldX, currentY - oldY));
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    public void circle() {
        currentX = 0;
        currentY = 0;
        oldX = 0;
        oldY = 0;
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(oldX, oldY, (currentX - oldX), (currentX - oldX)));
                repaint();
            }});}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all your previously selected shapes because their mousedown/mouseup events are still bound.

A straightforward way to solve this would be to keep track of your MouseAdapters (add them to a list when you bind them) and remove them (subsequently clearing the list) when you switch tools.